# Is a DeferredResult really improving the parallel execution of requests?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, deferred

I want to see a "proof" that a controller returning a DeferredResult is really better scaling up to many parallel request, than return just a plain value. To this end I came up with an example like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("weather")
public class WeatherController {
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public WeatherController() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    }

    @GetMapping("deferred")
    public DeferredResult<Weather> getWeatherDeferred() {
        DeferredResult<Weather> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        ListenableFutureTask<Weather> futureWeatherList = new ListenableFutureTask<>(
                () -> {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    return new Weather();
                });
        futureWeatherList.addCallback((weather) -> {
            result.setResult(weather);
        }, (throwable) -> {
            result.setErrorResult(throwable);
        });

        executorService.submit(futureWeatherList);
        return result;
    }

    @GetMapping("sync")
    public Weather getWeather() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return new Weather();
    }
}
```

When I send requests to the *deferred* and the *sync* getters from JMeter, I see no difference between the two methods whatsoever. I simulate 100 parallel users and run the requests 100 times. Absolutely no difference.
Can anybody give me an explanation? Does anybody have a better "proof" for the "superiority" of DeferredResults?

Comment: Why sleep in both? This concept only proves that you can write the getWeather() method with more complex code.

Comment: this is to simulate a long running operation, which is supposed to be identical in both cases - I'm making up an example to see any differences

Comment: What behaviour do you see and what difference exactly do you expect?

Comment: I run 100 requests in parallel from JMeter, 100 times. I expected that there are less waits for free dispatcher threads, when using the DeferredResult.